# How to decrese an image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create that every time that the image is clicked, it will decrease in size until it completely disappears. But I can't do this, help me!

HTML code:

```
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stupid Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header-top">
      <h1>Shrink the image</h1>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </header>
    <img src="D:\MATEUS\Programação\Stupid project\images\levi.png" alt="Levi" id="image">
  </body>
</html>
<script type="main/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

CSS code:

```
@import "variables.css";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap');

*
{
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.header-top
{
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  height: 49px;

}

.header-top > h1
{
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 10px 10px;
}

#image
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 90px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: By how much do you want it to decrease? How much in height and how much in width? How many times until it "dissapears"? Do you want to hide it completely or just make it too small to see? Anyway, you're going to need a counter for the button click and this Function Resize()
{
document.getElementById("image").height="100";
document.getElementById("image").width="100";
}  is how you change the dimensions in js. Btw, the jquery import you did goes in the <head> tag, not after the closed </html> (nothing should go after that).

Comment: While true, script references **can** go after the dom elements within a `<body>` element. However, `defer` replaces this method of loading the script references.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to scale the image down in size on each click we can do this:

- set the inital scale of the image to 1 (through a CSS variable --scale)
- set up an event listener on the image
- when the image is clicked read the current value of --scale, decrease it by 0.1, say, (as long as it hasn't already hit 0)

```html
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stupid Project</title><style>
*
{
  margin: 0%;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.header-top
{
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  height: 49px;

}

.header-top > h1
{
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 10px 10px;
}

#image
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 90px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: scale(var(--scale));
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header-top">
      <h1>Shrink the image</h1>
      <a href="#"></a>
    </header>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/768" alt="test picture" id="image">
    <script>
    const image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.style.setProperty('--scale', 1);
    image.addEventListener("click", function () {
       const curScale = image.style.getPropertyValue('--scale');
       if (curScale > 0) {image.style.setProperty('--scale', curScale - 0.1); }  
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the problem, here's the example code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="zoomout()">Click Me!</button>
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1108099/pexels-photo-1108099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" id="image">
```

CSS:

```
#image
{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 0px;   /* 90px */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#button
{
  color: white;
  margin-left: 570px;
  margin-top: 39px;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  background-color: var(--button-color);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function zoomout() {
  var GFG = document.getElementById("image");
  var currWidth = GFG.clientWidth;
  GFG.style.width = (currWidth - 100) + "px"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just reduce the image `width` one by one (or with whatever rate you wish), and to visualize this change have some transition set on the image.

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const imgWidth = getComputedStyle(img, null).getPropertyValue('width')

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = parseInt(imgWidth); i >= 0; i--) {
    img.style.width = `${i}px`
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618141411216-96de9f2bd309?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyN3x8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" />
```

Comment: Do I need to "declare" Jquery on Js?

Comment: No you don't need Jquery for this. @MateusCamillo